# Add multiple items in JSON array to object in C# using Json.net

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

Can anyone tell me how I can deserialize an object that contains multiple attributes?

Given the scenario below, the code works fine.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string json = @"{""name"": ""Person 2"",""email"": ""example@example.com""}";

    var emp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(json);
    Response.Write(emp.name + emp.email);
    return View();
}

public class Person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
}
```

But what do I have to do if the array contains multiple items, e.g

```
string json = @"{""data"": [{""name"": ""Person 1"",""email"": ""test@test.com""},{""name"": ""Person 2"",""email"": ""example@example.com""}]}";
```

Thanks in advance

The answers already given below were perfect for the problem I asked, but now I've gone one step ahead. Can anyone advise on what I'd need to do if the json had an array in it e.g. the addition of an address in?

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "Person 1",
            "email": "test@test.com",
            "address": {
                "address1": "my address 1",
                "address2": "my address 2" 
            } 
        },
        {
            "name": "Person 2",
            "email": "example@example.com",
            "address": {
                "address1": "my address 1",
                "address2": "my address 2" 
            } 
        } 
    ] 
}
```

Comment: If your `Person` class has also been extended with the `Address` class property then you shouldn't need to do any thing. Otherwise are you say that it hasn't and you've now got this "extra" property?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this has worked for me in the past:

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(json); // This would be the string you defined above
// The next line should yield a List<> of Person objects...
List<Person> list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Person>>(o["data"].ToString());
```

You might want to decorate your Person object as follows:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Person
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string name{get;set;}
    [JsonProperty]
    public string email{get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use an anonymous type.

```
var template = new { data = new Person[] { } };
Person[] emps = JsonConvert
    .DeserializeAnonymousType(json, template)
    .data;
```

Answer (score 1):

deserialize as :

```
public class JsonData
{
  public List<Person> Data {get;set;}
}
```